# Opening and closing multiple Angular Material Bottom Sheets

Tags: angularjs, angular-material, mddialog

Here goes the scenario I'm working on:

1. Our web app's business logic requires opening a number of dialogs one on top of another and closing them one by one (like the usual dialog UI stack)
2. This works splendidly with `mdDialog` using the `multiple: true` option
3. We are looking into converting the dialogs into sliding panels (from the right, if it matters) and after using CSS shenanigans we've re-purposed `mdBottomSheet` for that (it was the most useful for our use case, even if it originally opens from the bottom and not from the right)
4. It works with `multiple: true` as expected, since it's a re-purposed `mdDialog` (even if it's not documented properly) but it introduces a major issue...

**The issue:** Suppose you've open a main dialog and then a secondary. When you close the secondary it closes the main, too, which is not the intended result. Basically, closing a sub-dialog closes the main dialog (and all the other sub-dialogs, for that matter).

A solution we've found is using the `preserveScope: true` option, but it introduces a major resource leak, as it keeps the no-longer-relevant scopes of closed dialogs intact and running with all the related problems (faulty logic, unneeded watchers, errors on misisng DOM elements, etc.). Trying to kill any of the remnant scopes selectively after a dialog closes kills all the still open dialogs (same as having `preserveScope: false`...)

So basically, we're looking for a way to have the cake and eat it, too - have both the functionality of "bottom sheet" sliding from the right and functioning with multiple dialogs as a normal dialog would.

By the way, there are requests for Angular Material team to implement such functionality properly, but for now it's stuck in development limbo...

I would like some interesting ideas, if you know of such or can think of any (we're on the verge of either making `mdDialog` look like `mdBottomSheet` [thus re-implementing it ourselves, essentially] or re-implementing Redux for AngularJS to manage dialog states - and would really, really like to avoid either :) ).

**Versions:** AngularJS (angular 1.6.6) and Angular Material (angular-material 1.1.5)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, the actual solution I've found was to edit the definition of `MdBottomSheetDirective` and remove the `$destroy` event listener.

So, instead of:

```
/* @ngInject */
function MdBottomSheetDirective($mdBottomSheet) {
  return {
    restrict: 'E',
    link : function postLink(scope, element) {
      element.addClass('_md');     // private md component indicator for styling

      // When navigation force destroys an interimElement, then
      // listen and $destroy() that interim instance...
      scope.$on('$destroy', function() {
        $mdBottomSheet.destroy();
      });
    }
  };
}
```

I am using:

```
/* @ngInject */
function MdBottomSheetDirective($mdBottomSheet) {
  return {
    restrict: 'E',
    link : function postLink(scope, element) {
      element.addClass('_md');     // private md component indicator for styling
    }
  };
}
```

Surprisingly enough, it works completely as required with no side-effects (i.e. the dialog to be closed is closed with it's scope destroyed and no other dialog is affected) - even when navigating in the web-app.

If anyone has any idea why it works - I would be much obliged if you comment.